# How will it be in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-triggers

i have code for MySQL but i need to PostgreSQL. Can you help me convert from MySQL to PostgreSQL?

```
Create TRIGGER date_reservation
BEFORE INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF 
NEW.date_reservation IS NULL OR NEW.date_reservation = ''
THEN 
SET NEW.date_reservation = NOW();
END IF 
END
```

Comment: Title needs rewriting to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're asking us to convert code for you, but you haven't showed any effort toward solving the problem. SO isn't a code-conversion site, instead, we expect you to research and try, many, many times, and when you can't figure out the solution for days THEN ask. "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
will help.

Comment: There is nothing unclear about this question.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, your first need to create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION date_reservation_function()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.date_reservation IS NULL OR NEW.date_reservation = '' THEN
        NEW.date_reservation := NOW();
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Then, you create a trigger that invokes the function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER date_reservation_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE date_reservation_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

In both MySQL and Postgres, I would recommend that you simply do this using a default value:

```
create table date_reservation (
    . . . 
    date_reservation timestamp default now(),
    . . . 
);
```

You can actually do something similar in MySQL.